# VS2017: Solution builds but publish fails

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution with 3 Websites and 1 Web API project. When I build the solution there is no issue but when I publish the Web API project to file folder, I get a lot of errors and the publish fails. One of the error is:

> Error CS0006  Metadata file
>   'D:\Projects\MyAppName\Code\MyAppName\BusinessObjects\bin\Release\BusinessObjects.dll'
>   could not be found.

Other issues are similar to:

> Error CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Amazon' could not be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I have checked in the project. The referenced DLL(Amazon) is available and this issue doesn't occur when I build the solution.

What could be the issue? I have also checked if there is any missing file(checking for yellow exclamation icon in front of file name) but I couldn't find one.

Comment: Are you sure you have checked the Release folder, do you have the file in the Debug folder?

Comment: @WojtekT I checked and the DLLs are there in bin/Debug folder but nothing is in bin/Release folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> VS2017: Solution builds but publish fails

(*According to the error messages, they are all common errors. we could not give the most direct correct answer for this issue, we can only give you some troubleshootings. In order to avoid losing contact in the round-trip comments, I post those troubleshootings as answer instead of comments.*).

You can try:

- Clean solution then rebuild it.
- Go to **Solution Explorer**. Right click on Solution. Go to **Properties**. Go to **Configuration Manager**. Check if the checkboxes under **Build** are checked or not. If any or all of them are unchecked, then check them and try build the solution again.
- Remove the project reference and then adding it back in again, and check if all those missing dll file exists in the bin folder.
- Delete bin/obj folder, build again and try to restart Visual Studio.

Comment: Remove the reference, add it again, build solution and publish. Did this for each reference. Repeated it unless it worked :-)

Comment: @astm1982, Glad to know this helps you.